# Node.js convention for module require variable names

Tags: node.js

Just about all the Node.js code I’ve seen on the internet uses this convention for requiring modules, where the return value of `require` is assigned to a variable with the same name as the module:

```
var path = require('path');
var url = require('url');
```

The trouble is that that many module names are quite common words that we would like to use for variable names elsewhere in our code—e.g. `var path = path.join(basePath, fileName)`—which will probably cause problems due to name shadowing.

Of course, we could choose a different name for the module variable to avoid name clashes (e.g. `pathModule` or uppercase `Path`), but that seems to break with the convention.  Or we could choose a different name for variables elsewhere in the code—e.g. `var thePath = path.join(...)`.  What is most commonly done in this case?

Comment: weird. i've never run into a case where i wanted to name a variable `path` or `url` other than when requiring a module named that.

Comment: Downvotes and close votes are nice, but without some comments, I would have no idea how to improve the question or ask better ones in the future.

Comment: the close votes are self explanatory. downvote is probably for a wrong reason, though I guess one can argue not useful since it's just an opinion?

Comment: The downvotes aren't.

Comment: For close votes, all I see is "close(4)". The tooltip says "one more vote needed to close this question". That doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: You'll see the reason when it gets 5 votes. But, just to simplify things, it's getting closed because it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: There are lots of possible answers here that are not only opinion if people explain their reasoning.  This question should NOT get closed.  The OP could change their wording to ask "what is a good design pattern for ..." and people might not be quite as quick to close.  Fact is, this is a perfectly reasonable question with many possible good answers that are not entirely opinion.

Comment: Perhaps eslint could be configured to help catch these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the module name as is: It's IMHO common practice in Node.js to refer to the `bla` module using the variable `bla`.

Instead, I'd recommend to be more specific with your variable names when it comes to concrete usage, e.g.:

```
var path = path.join(basePath, fileName);
```

You don't do this just for fun, you do this for a specific file for a specific reason. E.g., you want to load a configuration file. Then rename the variable to `configurationPath` or something like this:

```
var configurationPath = path.join(basePath, fileName);
```

Having a variable just named `path` is quite … well, it doesn't tell you much of the story. Instead, the `path` module is actually about `path`s, so it's okay to name it like this.

Hope this helps.

PS: Most probably, even `configurationPath` is a bad name, but this entirely depends on your situation and what's your intent. I just used it as an example, don't take it literally.

Comment: A good answer with defensible logic and rationale, proving that this question doesn't need to be closed as only opinion-based.  I sure hope we can discuss good design patterns here on StackOverflow without everything getting closed as opinion-based.  As a point of fact to all you "quick-to-vote-close" people, more than 50% of the answers here on SO are someone's opinion.  What you're looking for is well reasoned opinion that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your nice comment and the compliment :-)

Comment: To add to this answer - It is pretty important for the readability and understandability of your code that common modules are assigned to a variable name that matches the module.  That will make your code a lot more recognizable to other developers that know nodejs and will even keep to a consistent name within your various files.  If you make up your own variable name to assign the module to, then when people see code using that other variable name, they will not immediately know what it is and your code will be not as easy to understand.  So, pick different names for your own variables.

Comment: I guess the take-away from this answer should be to avoid generic variable names where possible. Generic variable names may be appropriate when writing suitably abstract functions—`function isDirectory(path)`—I guess we should just use something else like `thePath` or `somePath`.

Comment: When the variable is a parameter, avoiding generic name seems forced to me, or event redundant. Eg. `createConfigurationFile(configurationFilePath, config)` doesn't seem to add more clarity, since `createConfigurationFile(path, config)` is really quite self-explanatory.